# Bazel rules that use different subsets of genrule outputs

Tags: bazel

I have a code generator that produces three output files:

- client.cpp
- server.cpp
- data.h

The **genrule** looks like this:

```
genrule(
  name = 'code_gen',
  tools = [ '//tools:code_gen.sh' ],
  outs = [ 'client.cpp', 'server.cpp', 'data.h' ],
  local = True,
  cmd = '$(location //tools:code_gen.sh) $(@D)')
```

The 'client.cpp' and 'server.cpp' each have their own **cc_library** rule.

My question is how to depend on the **genrule** but only use a specific output file.

What I did is create a macro that defined the **genrule** with specific *outs* set to the file required, but this resulted in multiple execution of the **genrule**:

***gen.bzl***:

```
def code_generator(
  name,
  out):
  native.genrule(
    name = name,
    tools = [ '//bazel:gen.sh' ],
    outs = [ out ],
    local = True,
    cmd = '$(location //bazel:gen.sh) $(@D)')
```

***BUILD***

```
load(':gen.bzl', 'code_generator')
code_generator('client_cpp', 'client.cpp')
code_generator('server_cpp', 'server.cpp')
code_generator('data_h', 'data.h')

cc_library(
  name = 'client',
  srcs = [ ':client_cpp' ],
  hdrs = [ ':data_h' ],
)

cc_library(
  name = 'server',
  srcs = [ ':server_cpp' ],
  hdrs = [ ':data_h' ],
)
```

Is there a way to depend on a genrule making it run once and then use only selected outputs from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just use the filename (e.g. `:server.cpp`) to depend on a specific output of a rule.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how will bazel tie sever.cpp to the file generated by the genrule?

Comment: If your `code_gen` genrule would is a rule with 3 outputs: `client.cpp`, `server.cpp` and `data.h` then, since file has a corresponding label, they would be denoted `//<pkg>:client.cpp`, `//<pkg>:server.cpp` and `//<pkg>:data.h` where `<pkg>` is the package of `code_gen`.

Comment: In my case, there's also a file, `example.pb.go`, in the repo (I'm trying to follow https://dev.to/bazel/bazel-can-write-to-the-source-folder-b9b) and `bazel` is using the repo copy when using `:example.pb.go`. Any way to reference the one in the cache?